# Retrieve last uploaded file directory from FTP server

Tags: c#, file, directory, ftp

I'm here to ask if there is any C# function that allows me to discover the directory of the last uploaded file by a certain `FtpWebRequest` or `Stream`, so I can store it in a MySQL database later on?

This Function:

```
    public static string uploadftp(string filename, string ftpserver, string user, string pass)
    {
        System.Net.FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpserver);
        
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        FileStream file = File.OpenRead(filename);
        int length = Convert.ToInt32(file.Length);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        do
        {
            bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, length);
            ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        while (bytesRead != 0);

        file.Close();
        
        //supposed get directory code

        ftpStream.Close();
        //return directory
    }
```

Comment: Where does this uploading take place, in your own code?

Comment: Edited the post to include the current function I've... What I'm asking is what should I put in the place of //supposed get directory code...

Comment: I still don't understand what your problem is: don't you already have `filename` and `ftpserver` variables?

Comment: Good point... So if I store the image name, and the on the website script (yes, this "includes" a website), just do something like `echo "<img src='\imagens\" . $filename . "' />"` would that work?

Comment: You will probably want to use something like [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) to remove the local path. But shouldn't `ftpserver` actually contain the name of the **remote** file?

Comment: Yes, yes! Thanks! Sometimes people (in this case me) should keep things simple, instead of complicating. Thank you very much!

Comment: I just updated the comment: I believe that `ftpserver` variable actually contains the remote file name, right?

Comment: The `ftpserver` is basically just saying "localhost" (it's stored in Settings.settings) at this moment, so no... And the FileZila server redirects the user in question automatically to the `/imagens/` folder, so no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file watcher for your root folder of your FTP folder. it will be triggered when the file is uploaded with the file name and you can store it in mysql.